# How to set model attribute for every action

Tags: grails

earlier I use Spring MVC and annotation @ModelAttribute.

```
@Controller
public class ArticleController {

    @ModelAttribute("articles")
    public List<Testset> getArticles(){
        return articleDao.all();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/first.htm")
    public void first(){                       

    } 
}
```

How can made this behaviour in Grails controller?

```
class ArticleController{

    //this variable I want to in every action
    List articles 

    def first = { }   
    def second = { } 
    def third = { } 
}
```

Of course I can use this code for every action

```
def first = {
  this.articles = Article.all()
}
```

but I want not this.

Thank very much for your help.
Tomáš

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define an after interceptor and add data to the model there:

```
class ArticleController {

   def afterInterceptor = { model ->
      model.articles = Article.list()
   }

   def first = { }   
   def second = { } 
   def third = { } 
}
```

The docs for this are here: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/afterInterceptor.html